# Swift. Key Value in Dictionary

Tags: swift, словари, swift4

У меня возник вопрос касательно того как сделать несколько ключей для одного значения. Или возможно есть другой выход.
Нужно чтобы ключами была маленькая и большая буква "a", "A":

```
var hiraganaDictionary = ["a":"あ", "i":"い", "u":"う", "e":"え", "o":"お"]
```

Но в данном словаре только один ключ.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Смотря для чего Вам это необходимо. Впоследствии можно же просто игнорировать регистр.

Answer (score 1):

Другой выход:

```
var hiraganaDictionary = ["a":"あ", "i":"い", "u":"う", "e":"え", "o":"お",
                          "A":"あ", "I":"い", "U":"う", "E":"え", "O":"お"]
```